# Apply a range filter on an array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I'm running into trouble finding an efficient way to filter my data. What I got so far:

A structure like this:

```
struct BasicData {
    let n0 : Double!
    let n1 : Double!
    let n2 : Double!
}
var basicData = [BasicData]()
```

After appending the Array using:

```
basicData.append(BasicData(n0: 55.15, n1: 5.1, n2: 2))
basicData.append(BasicData(n0: 2, n1: 2.1, n2: 25))
basicData.append(BasicData(n0: 45.15, n1: 5.1, n2: 15))
```

I want to create a new Array that contains all elements whose `n0 > 5 && n0 < 50` and `n2 > 7 && n2 < 40`

Comment: Why are `BasicData`'s properties declared as IUOs if you're giving them values upon initialisation? You should make them non-optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments by @Hamish you should make your structs properties non-optionals:

```
struct BasicData {
    let n0, n1, n2: Double
}
```

To filter your array you can use the range pattern operator `~=`. If you need to make your range start from the first fraction number greater than the lower bound of your range you can use Double property `.nextUp` as follow:

```
let filtered = basicData.filter { 
    5.nextUp..<50 ~= $0.n0 && 7.nextUp..<40 ~= $0.n2 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let filteredData = basicData.filter({$0.n0 > 5 && $0.n0 < 50 && $0.n2 > 7 && $0.n2 < 40})
```